# Do I have a Schengen entry ban if I was arrested in the UK for immigration violation?

Tags: uk, schengen, customs-and-immigration, denial-of-entry

I have been arrested by immigration enforcment in the UK for working with fraudulent documents.

I am from a Balkan country and wanted to know whether this would mean that I also have a Schengen entry ban.

Comment: You probably do not have a ban yet unless there is more to your story, but the Schengen countries might have information on you that makes the grant of a visa unlikely if you need one. Are you from an Annex II country? Then you need no visa for entry, just for work.

Comment: @o.m. The only Balkan nationality that's not Annex II is Kosovo

Comment: I suppose we should assume that you're not from a Balkan country that is a member of the EU.

Comment: Close-voters, the question is only asking about entry to the Schengen area. It says nothing about long-term visits or anything like that. This question is squarely on-topic, here.

Comment: @Coke ...if you don't consider the Balkan countries that are EU members.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot answer with any certainty whether you have a Schengen ban.  However, it does seem quite clear that any such ban could not be issued by the United Kingdom.  See the europa.eu page on the [Schengen Information System](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen-information-system_en):

> The United Kingdom operates the SIS but, as it has chosen not to join the Schengen area, the UK cannot issue or access Schengen-wide alerts for refusing entry or stay into the Schengen area.