# Does UK entry ban effect entry to schengen or eu countries?

Tags: eu

If UK operates sis and at the same time it has no access to issue wide alerts or entry ban to schengen then what’s the function UK can do operating sis?

Comment: What do you mean by 'sis'? The [Schengen Information System](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen-information-system_en)? Your title appears entirely unrelated to your question.

Comment: @Roddy of the Frozen Peas It’s from the OP’s original question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/125808/do-i-have-a-schengen-entry-ban-if-i-was-arrested-in-the-uk-for-immigration-viola/132618#132618

Comment: You have created two accounts (https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/92577/alexa and https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/92578/alexa).  You can [merge them](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Are you saying your sister is getting medical attention in the UK, or what are you saying?

Comment: @Alexa Everything related to law enforcement https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen-information-system_en EXCEPT issue or access Schengen-wide alerts for refusing entry and stay into the Schengen area.